# How to truncate double precision value in PostgreSQL by keeping exactly first two decimals?

Tags: json, postgresql, rounding, plpgsql, truncated

I'm trying to truncate **double precision** value when I'm build json using `json_build_object()` function in **PostgreSQL 11.8** but with no luck. To be more precise I'm trying to truncate **19.9899999999999984** number to ONLY two decimals but making sure it DOES NOT round it to 20.00 (which is what it does), but to keep it at **19.98**.

BTW, what I've tried so far was to use:
1) `TRUNC(found_book.price::numeric, 2)` and I get value **20.00**
2) `ROUND(found_book.price::numeric, 2)` and I get value **19.99** -> so far this is closesest value but not what I need
 
3) `ROUND(found_book.price::double precision, 2)`  and I get

> [42883] ERROR: function round(double precision, integer) does not exist

Also here is whole code I'm using:

```
create or replace function public.get_book_by_book_id8(b_id bigint) returns json as
$BODY$
declare
    found_book book;
    book_authors json;
    book_categories json;
    book_price double precision;
begin
    -- Load book data:
    select * into found_book
    from book b2
    where b2.book_id  = b_id;

    -- Get assigned authors
    select case when count(x) = 0 then '[]' else json_agg(x) end into book_authors
    from (select aut.*
        from book b
        inner join author_book as ab on b.book_id = ab.book_id
        inner join author as aut on ab.author_id = aut.author_id
        where b.book_id = b_id) x;

    -- Get assigned categories
    select case when count(y) = 0 then '[]' else json_agg(y) end into book_categories
    from (select cat.*
        from book b
        inner join category_book as cb on b.book_id = cb.book_id
        inner join category as cat on cb.category_id = cat.category_id
        where b.book_id = b_id) y;

    book_price = trunc(found_book.price, 2);
    -- Build the JSON response:
    return (select json_build_object(
        'book_id', found_book.book_id,
        'title', found_book.title,
        'price', book_price,
        'amount', found_book.amount,
        'is_deleted', found_book.is_deleted,
        'authors', book_authors,
        'categories', book_categories
    ));
end
$BODY$
language 'plpgsql';

select get_book_by_book_id8(186);
```

How do I achieve to keep EXACTLY ONLY two FIRST decimal digits 19.**98** (any suggestion/help is greatly appreciated)?

**P.S.** PostgreSQL version is 11.8

Comment: What is your exact PostgreSQL version ? I cannot reproduce in 12.3. What is the data type of `found_book.price` ?

Comment: @pifor: it's PostgreSQL 11.8

Comment: You'll have to add a complete SQL statement that displays the undesirable rounding. I am not sure what exactly you are doing.

Comment: What's the original data type of `found_book.price`? That you pass the result into `json_build_object` should not matter.

Comment: @Bergi: it's `double precision` (found_book.price)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: I've added code you have asked for and added additonal tag for plgpgsql which I've missed (sorry for that)

Comment: BTW, I've also added (i.e. declared) NEW variable `book_price` to try to achieve what @pifor suggested in his answer, but no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [PostgreSQL 11.8](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0f565a7912983311df88e79f4e677154) or [12.3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0f565a7912983311df88e79f4e677154) I cannot reproduce:

```
# select trunc('19.9899999999999984'::numeric, 2);
 trunc 
-------
 19.98
(1 row)

# select trunc(19.9899999999999984::numeric, 2);
 trunc 
-------
 19.98
(1 row)

# select trunc(19.9899999999999984, 2);
 trunc 
-------
 19.98
(1 row)
```

Actually I can reproduce with the right type and a special setting:

```
# set extra_float_digits=0;
SET
# select trunc(19.9899999999999984::double precision::text::numeric, 2);
 trunc 
-------
 19.99
(1 row)
```

And a possible solution:

```
# show extra_float_digits;
 extra_float_digits 
--------------------
 3
(1 row)

select  trunc(19.9899999999999984::double precision::text::numeric, 2);
 trunc 
-------
 19.98
(1 row)
```

But note that:

> Note: The extra_float_digits setting controls the number of extra
>   significant digits included when a floating point value is converted
>   to text for output. With the default value of 0, the output is the
>   same on every platform supported by PostgreSQL. Increasing it will
>   produce output that more accurately represents the stored value, but
>   may be unportable.

Comment: I've updated my question with code of `json_build_object()` function that I'm using so it's clear I can not pass numeric value as a string (like in your first and second example).

Comment: Strange, I cannot reproduce that on Fedora 30 with PostgreSQL 12.3.

Comment: I agree: I cannot reproduce with PG 12.3. But it works with PG 11.8 on Centos 7.8.2003.

Comment: @pifor : can this 3 time casting (double precision>text>numeric) impose any kind of performance issues...like slowing down execution time, that is make it last longer in very obvious way for let's say 2000 records (**book** instances)?

Comment: @NikolaS: a quick test does not show overhead using psql `\timing` when running the 3 conversions with `SELECT` versus just displaying the  number with `SELECT` 19...` without any conversion. There should be no performance issue.

Comment: @NikolaS: however you should take into consideration that this solution does not work with the PostgreSQL version 12.

Comment: @pifor: so in case of migrating to new version (let's say 12.3 version) my code will break and I need to find some other workaround ...or just manually change code when switching to new PostgreSQL version?

Comment: @NikolaS: yes you need to find a workaround. If possible try to switch to `numeric` because as doc. says: *if you require exact storage and calculations (such as for monetary amounts), use the numeric type instead.*

Answer (score 1):

As @pifor suggested I've managed to get it done by directly passing `trunc(found_book.price::double precision::text::numeric, 2)` as value in json_build_object like this:

```
json_build_object(
        'book_id', found_book.book_id,
        'title', found_book.title,
        'price', trunc(found_book.price::double precision::text::numeric, 2),
        'amount', found_book.amount,
        'is_deleted', found_book.is_deleted,
        'authors', book_authors,
        'categories', book_categories
    )
```

Using `book_price = trunc(found_book.price::double precision::text::numeric, 2);` and passing it as value for **'price'** key didn't work.

Thank you for your help. :)